# How to convert video using HandBrake?

Tags: command-line, tools

I have FansConvert site that convert anime and movie into mobile device format, especially 3gp and mp4. I made it to help people who don't have a computer, or are not able to watch on the computer. Another reason is because not everyone has good internet connection to download videos with big size for desktop version.

I usually use online tool http://video.online-convert.com to convert video less than 100MB and use desktop application AVS Video Converter for video more than 100MB. I know to convert big size video will take a time, and need computer with good specification for good performance.

I have VPS, so I think to use it to convert video that has a size more than 100MB.

I tried FFMPEG, but failed. And then I found HandBrake for converting video. But the problem is I do not know how to set the output file I convert.

On HandBrake wiki https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide, there are many options offer. I try to convert mkv to mp4 format using command:

```
HandBrakeCLI -i video.mkv -o video.mp4 -e x264 -q 22 -r 15 -b 128 -B 32 -X 320 -Y 240
```

And it still failled. The output not as I expected.

I need help, how to convert video into mp4 format with specification:

```
Screen size: 320 x 240 pixel
Video Bitrate: 128 kbps
Audio quality: 32 kbps
Frame rate: 15 per second
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: try using the gui: `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk`

Comment: That said, [openshot](http://openshot.org/) has much more options when it comes to converting: `sudo apt-get install openshot`

Comment: According to the [HandBrake features page](https://handbrake.fr/features.php) the supported outputs are: `.MP4(.M4V) and .MKV`. So, your only choice is openshot.

Answer (score 1):

What output do you expect? I ran your command on an old random DVD rip of mine and found the bitrates were a little too high but the image size and rate were right.

But you have to remember that the numbers you give are compression *goals*, not limits. If you want to go further, you need to lower the framesize, frame rate or sample rate (for audio). And even then, some codecs just have too much overhead to go *that* low.

```
HandBrakeCLI -i input.avi -o out.mp4 -e x264 -r 15 -b 128 -B 32 -R44.1 -X 320 -Y 140
```

That got me a fair bit closer (computed 123 kbps video, 60kbps audio) but past that you're going to get really horrible results. They're already fairly crappy.